# r caretEnsemble - passing a fit param to one specific model in caretList

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I have some code which fits several (cross-validated) models to some data, as below.

```
library(datasets)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

# load data
data("iris")

# establish cross-validation structure
set.seed(32)
trainControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", 
                             number=5, repeats=3, # 3x 5-fold CV
                             search="random")

algorithmList <- c('lda',         # Linear Discriminant Analysis 
                   'rpart' ,      # Classification and Regression Trees
                   'svmRadial')   # SVM with RBF Kernel

# cross-validate models from algorithmList
models <- caretList(Species~., data=iris, trControl=trainControl, methodList=algorithmList)
```

so far so good. however, if I add `'gbm'` to my `algorithmList`, I get a ton of extraneous log messages because `gbm` seems to have a `verbose=TRUE` default fit param.

According to the [caret docs](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html), if I were running `train` on `method='gbm'` by itself (not along with several models trained in a `caretList`), I could simply add `verbose=FALSE` to `train()`, which would flow through to `gbm`. But this throws an error when I try it in `caretList`.

So I would like to pass `verbose=FALSE` (or any other fit param, in theory) specifically to one particular model from `caretList`'s `methodList`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok this is actually addressed well in the docs.

```
?caretList
```

includes:

> tuneList:     optional, a NAMED list of caretModelSpec objects. This is
>   much more flexible than methodList and allows the specificaiton of
>   model-specific parameters

And I've confirmed my problem is solved if instead of:

```
algorithmList <- c('lda',         # Linear Discriminant Analysis 
                   'rpart' ,      # Classification and Regression Trees
                   'svmRadial',   # SVM with RBF Kernel
                   'gbm')         # Gradient-boosted machines
```

I use:

```
modelTypes <- list(lda      = caretModelSpec(method="lda"),
                   rpart    = caretModelSpec(method="rpart"),
                   svmRadial= caretModelSpec(method="svmRadial"),
                   gbm      = caretModelSpec(method="rf", verbose=FALSE)
```

...then the `models <- caretList(...` line goes from:

```
models <- caretList(... methodList=algorithmList)
```

to:

```
models <-caretList(...  tuneList = modelTypes)
```